# FromBody value not overwriting default parameter value after migrating to .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following endpoint implemented in .Net Core 3.1 WebApi. The TestFilter object has a list parameter TestTypes. TestTypes gets a default TestType value once it is constructed. When the endpoint gets called with the TestFilter parameter I would expect that the default value would be replaced with the incoming value. Instead it's added to the list so the default value is still part of it.

This worked when using .Net472 but after migrating to .Net Core 3.1 the default value is always part of the array.

Is there a way to specify to overwrite the default parameter value if it's supplied by the client?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTests([FromBody] TestFilter filter)
    {
         // Call repo
    }
    
  public class TestFilter
  {
     public IReadOnlyCollection<TestType> TestTypes { get; set; }
     public string Description;

    TestFilter() {
            TestTypes = new List
                      {
                         new TestType("AdvancedTest", 10)
                      };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `TestFilter` like this:

```
public class TestFilter
        {
            public IReadOnlyCollection<TestType> TestTypes { get; set; } = new List<TestType>{new TestType("AdvancedTest", 10)};
            public string Description;

        }
```

TestType:

```
public class TestType
        {
            public string v1 { get; set; }
            public int v2 { get; set; }
            public TestType() { }
            public TestType(string v1, int v2)
            {
                this.v1 = v1;
                this.v2 = v2;
            }
        }
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

I use the following classes and it can work.

```
public class TestFilter: TestBaseFilter
        {
            
            public string Description;

        }
        public class TestBaseFilter
        {
            public IReadOnlyCollection<TestType> TestTypes { get; set; } = new List<TestType> { new TestType("AdvancedTest", 10) };
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work either

Comment: I test in .net core 3.1,and it can work,you can have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Nice, does it also work if you put the initialization into the constructor?

Comment: No,i remove the constructor as in my answer.

Comment: Could you create a TestFilter : TestBaseFilter class and move the ReadOnlyCollection into the baseclass. If you initialize the array from there does it still work? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes,it can work.

Comment: Thanks, I still can't get it to work. I didn't specify that I am actually using a generic baseclass TestBaseFilter<AdvancedTestDto> to handle different dto's. Not sure if this is affecting it.